# How to drop columns from a pandas DataFrame that have elements containing a string?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is not about dropping columns whose name contains a string.

I have a dataframe with 1600 columns. Several hundred are garbage. Most of the garbage columns contain a phrase such as `invalid value encountered in double_scalars (XYZ)` where `XYZ' is a filler name for the column name.

I would like to delete all columns that contain, in any of their elements, the string `invalid`

Purging columns with strings in general would work too. What I want is to clean it up so I can fit a machine learning model to it, so removing any/all columns that are not boolean or real would work.

This must be a duplicate question, but I can only find answers to how to remove a column with a specific column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.select_dtypes(include=[float,bool]`) or `df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])`

Link to docs https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html

Comment: The OP said they want to remove columns that contain `invalid`.

Comment: @richardec question formulation is kinda controversial. I just thought that _What I want is to clean it up so I can fit a machine learning model to it, so removing any/all columns that are not boolean or real would work_ this is the final requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` to make a mask checking if each column contains `invalid`, and then pass that mask to the second position of `.loc`:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.apply(lambda col: col.astype(str).str.contains('invalid')).any()]
```